# unable to use the 13.04 applications after login

Tags: unity, usability

Installed 13.04 and after login the desktop files are displayed for the home folder.
But I am not sure how to run applications moving the muse to the edges shows nothing.

I can use <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>T</kbd> and  <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Q</kbd> and can press Mail and Web dedicated buttons from the keyboard but I want to install my previous apps especially Gnome, so how can I call up the sotware centre?

Answer (score 0):

I don't know what you mean to install *"Gnome"* since you are in fact using *"Gnome 3"*. In any case, moving the mouse to the upper left corner and/or clicking there, should bring you the Dash. In the Unity's case moving the pointer to the left edge should be enough.

If you want to initiate the Ubuntu Software Center there are a couple of ways.

1. Bring up the dash, either moving the mouse to the upper left corner or pressing the <kbd>Meta</kbd> (or <kbd>Windows</kbd>) key then type 'software center'
2. Press <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>F2</kbd> and type 'software-center', then press enter.
3. Open a terminal and type `software-center`, then press enter.

Comment: Thanks very much for the answers but they did not help in my case. The shortcuts did not work as the Unity interface is not complete. I am using the Home directory from my 12.04 installation so a script there may have been stopping something. Anyway I logged in using the guest and it had the complete Unity interface with top bar and left icons so I could install Gnome compete. I prefer Gnome 2 (no effects)

Comment: @SteveAllen I think that what you needed was deleting the personal preferences using `rm -r ~/.*` in your user, then restart the session.